# Unable to connect to https://myserver/VaultService

Tags: sourcegear-vault

I have just installed Vault on my machine, I intend touse it single user.

When trying to use it for the first time, I get the error message below.

Is there anything I should enable?
I have the correct passwords.
I am using the Admin account.

I have Windows * 64 bits, Vault is also 64 bits.

[image]

Thanks to Beth's answer below, now I can at least visualise the following page, but still not be able to follow the links in it.

[image]

This is the result I get when I click on the links(Picture below).

Error messages are below, but the formatting is not good.

```
Most likely causes: The request matched a wildcard mime map. 
The request is mapped to the static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the request will map to a different handler. 


 Things you can try: If you want to serve this content as a static file, add an explicit MIME map. 

Detailed Error Information: Module    StaticFileModule  Notification  ExecuteRequestHandler  Handler    StaticFile  Error Code    0x80070032


Requested URL    http://vrindavana:80/VaultService/Admin/default.aspx  Physical Path    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VaultService\Admin\default.aspx  

Logon Method    Anonymous  
Logon User    Anonymous
```

[image]

IIS:
I have IIS installed and if I browse it I see what's on the picture below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the update.

The error seems to indicate a problem with the .NET Framework. Here are the next steps you should try.

1)  Register the .NET framework with IIS.  Run a command-prompt as administrator and then change directories until you get to the highest version of the 4.x .NET framework.  It might look something like `cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.net\framework64\v4.0.30319`, but I'm not sure of the entire path on your machine.  Then run the command `aspnet_regiis -i`.

Then try your web page again.

2)  If you then get a 404.2 error, then open your IIS Manager, click on the machine name and then click on ISAPI and CGI restrictions.  Make sure the .NET frameworks are set to Allow there.

Comment: Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.33440
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.33440).
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlin
k/?LinkID=216771.
Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.33440).

Comment: What OS version do you have?

Answer (score 2):

First try reaching the Vault server using a browser.  Try the URL `http://<your Vault server name>/vaultservice/index.html`.  If you can not reach that page, then change  to either the [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) or the IP address.

If you still cannot reach the index.html page, then try reaching it using a browser right on the server and use localhost.  The URL would then be `http://localhost/vaultservice/index.html`.

Let me know the results of these URLs first and then I'll give you next steps.

Beth

SourceGear Technical Support

Comment: The links on the Vault index page aren't always what your DNS is set up to resolve.  Since  http://<your Vault server name>/vaultservice/index.html worked for you, next try to go to the URL  http://<your Vault server name>/vaultservice/vaultservice.asmx.  If that works, then go to  http://<your Vault server name>/vaultservice/vaultweb and login.