# Moving away from Source-Safe but having problems installing SourceGear Vault on IIS 10

Tags: iis, version-control, installation, iis-10, sourcegear-vault

In order to keep my scripts I used to use `Microsoft source safe` but [after many issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1224554/1501497), I migrated to [sourceGear Vault](https://sourcegear.com/vault/), which stores all the data in a few `sql server databases`, so that you can backup them, etc.

This question is specific to this version control system called [SourceGear Vault](https://sourcegear.com/vault/).

In the past I had [problems with SourceGear Vault installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609743/unable-to-connect-to-https-myserver-vaultservice) and they were fixed.

Now again I am finding it not straight forward to install the SourceGear Vault client.

**What I have done so far**

I have used the following powershell commands to install the server and client:

```
msiexec /i VaultProServer64_10_0_0_30736.msi

msiexec /i VaultProClient_10_0_0_30736.msi
```

The server installation went on without major problems, other that you need to make sure you run the powershell above as `Administrator`. Same is valid for the client install.

Client install is ok too, the bit that I have got a problem is the IIS.

to find the version of IIS on powershell:

```
powershell "get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\  | select setupstring,versionstring"
```

[image]

[About the .NET version(s) I have installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487265/powershell-script-to-return-versions-of-net-framework-on-a-machine/3495491#3495491)
running the below Powershell script I get:

```
Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse |
Get-ItemProperty -name Version,Release -EA 0 |
Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} |
Select PSChildName, Version, Release, @{
  name="Product"
  expression={
      switch -regex ($_.Release) {
        "378389" { [Version]"4.5" }
        "378675|378758" { [Version]"4.5.1" }
        "379893" { [Version]"4.5.2" }
        "393295|393297" { [Version]"4.6" }
        "394254|394271" { [Version]"4.6.1" }
        "394802|394806" { [Version]"4.6.2" }
        "460798" { [Version]"4.7" }
        {$_ -gt 460798} { [Version]"Undocumented 4.7 or higher, please update script" }
      }
    }
}
```

[image]

this is my current IIS SourceGear Environment:

[image]

**The Application Pools**

> In the IIS Manager, click on Application Pools.  there are multiple
>   pools for Vault.  Check the Advanced Settings for each and look for
>   "Enable 32-bit Apps."  That should be set to False.

I have all disabled the `Enabled 32-bits Apps` as you can see on the pictures below:

[image]

I show only one of the application pools but they are all set the same.
[image]

I had the following error but it is fixed now - see below for more info:

when I go to the `http://localhost/vaultservice/index.html` using google chrome,
I get the following error message:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>
> Error Code       0x80070021
>
> Config Error     This configuration section cannot be used at this
>   path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level.
>   Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set
>   explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy
>   allowOverride="false".

[image]

[This locked at parental level was fixed by doing the following:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock)

I needed to change from `read only` to `read/write` some of the features: `handler mappings` and `modules`

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

**The error message when using the application**

This is the error message I am currently getting when connecting using the Vault client:

> Unable to connect to http://mathura/VaultService.  No server was found
>   at the specified URL.  Please verify your network settings using the
>   Options dialog under the Tools menu in the Vault GUI Client.  Web
>   Exception: The request failed with HTTP status 405: Method Not
>   Allowed.

[image]

How can I troubleshoot this and get to a healthy installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

when going to `http://mathura/VaultService/VaultService.asmx`
I was getting the following error:

> The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension
>   configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file
>   should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Then from the question below:

[“The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration.” error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388066/the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-because-of-the-extension-configura)

> I had to check .NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services > WCF Services >
>   HTTP Activation

and that solved my problem.

BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]